# Determining Causality From Discrete Impulse Response

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, linear-systems

Trying to wrap my mind around the concepts of this one...

> Consider the following impulse response $h[n]$ for a linear, time-invariant system:
>   $$
> h[n] =\left\{\underline{1} , -2, 2, -1\right\}
> $$
>   where n=0 starts at 1 for h[n]
>
> - (a) Is the system causal? Why or why not?
> - (b) Is the system stable? Why or why not?
> - (c) Is the system FIR or IIR? Give a reason for your answer.
> - (d) Does the system have memory? why or why not?

Based on my understanding I've concluded...

- (a):  ?
- (b): Yes the system is stable because the summation of |h[n]| is less than infinity.
- (c): The system is an FIR (Finite Impulse System) because the duration of h[x] is not infinite. It has a finite number of values.
- (d): This system is **not** memoryless, therefore has memory. This is because in order to be memoryless (to my understanding) an impulse response should not have values at any times other than n=0. h[n] has multiple values

**Updated the question to reflect how the values relate to time. The underlined 1 in h[n] denotes the origin n=0**

Comment: This is homework-style kind of question, the question won't be well-received unless you provide what you have tried or tell the community where you are stuck.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo h(n)  is the system's response to the input. where n is a unit in time. h is the impulse response of the system

Comment: All your conclusions are correct, but (a) can't be answered, as mentioned by Olli, because we don't know where in time to place those values given for $h[n]$.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo yes it is. I updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you've figured out how the given values for $h[n]$ relate to the time index $n$ (which is unclear in the current problem formulation), it should be easy to decide whether the given system is causal or not by considering the input-output relation of a discrete-time LTI system:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}h[k]x[n-k]\tag{1}$$

where $x[n]$ is the input sequence, and $y[n]$ is the output sequence.

For the system to be causal, the output at time $n$ must only depend on the current value or on past values of the input $x[n]$. What does that imply for the impulse response $h[n]$?

Comment: Updated the question to reflect how the values relate to time. The underlined 1 in h[n] denotes the origin n=0

Comment: @crazyCoder: OK, so now you should be able to answer (a), right?

Comment: No, I think I'm missing something conceptually. But I'm thinking that the system IS causal because for h[0] = 1, h[1] = -2, etc there is never an instance where h[n]=value where n < value. so for every instance n only depends on current and past values?

Comment: @crazyCoder: If you look at Eq. (1) in my answer you see that only the current and past values of $x[n]$ are used to compute $y[n]$ if and only if  $h[n]=0$ for $n<0$. So that's simply the condition for causality.